# Can Android app develop with C#.Net language and Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

When i searched in internet , i found android app can be developed with C#.Net and Visual Studio.

[Mono Droid](http://www.brutaldev.com/post/2011/01/15/Android-applications-in-C-using-Visual-Studio.aspx)

That framework name is MonoDroid.

Can it be to develope Android app with C#.Net and Visual Studio?

If it can be, is there any problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Doesn't the article you point to answer it?

Comment: i just want to know is there any problem (like erorr or bugs) when using that framework.

Comment: Mono is not integrated with VS, you need to use Mono's own IDE (monodev, if I am not mistaken).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Incorrect.  Mono for Android lets you use Visual Studio and installs plugins to automate the deployment and debugging process.

Comment: As far as the bugs go, be prepared to see a fair number of them. I tried mono once to code for mac, and discovered compatibility bugs in rather unexpected areas. This should come as no surprise when you have mono manufacturers in a constant catch-up game with Microsoft on one end and Google on the other.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Thanks, that is very nice to know. I tried mono for mac, and remember them shipping with monodev. VS integration is definitely a plus, because monodev was similar to VS of early 2000s, lacking manu usability features of the more modern IDEs.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I don't doubt it.  I give credit to the open/free IDEs out there and the people who make them, but since I started using VS-Professional I've never looked back.  As far as Mono compatibility, I've ported a large Silverlight framework over to MonoDroid and save for GUI code (naturally) it all converted and ran fine.  I've never tried Mono for Mac nor the full Mono framework so maybe that gave you a bad experience there; CoreCLR is definitely pretty compatible (if not restrictive).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can.  I've had issues sometimes getting the debugger to work, when it does work it's *painfully* slow, but otherwise Mono for Android seems pretty good.  Haven't done anything too major with it though.

Hard to comment as to what "any problem" is though.  It compiles, deploys, and works if that's what you want to know.  You can try it for free with the emulator.  Takes a while to setup.

Oh, I do have one big problem.  Usually when you deploy, it prompts you to start up an emulator.  It takes a long time to start the emulator the first time and then the build process doesn't show it as a valid emulator to deploy to.  I then have to shut down the virtual phone, redeploy, and the second time it launches much faster and it works fine for the rest of the Visual Studio session.

As a side note, you must use Visual Studio Professional; Express will not work with Mono for Android. (You can use MonoDevelop though if you still wish to use a free IDE)

Here are the documented limitations for Mono for Android: http://docs.xamarin.com/android/about/limitations and http://support.xamarin.com/customer/portal/topics/62116-android-faq/articles

Essentially, you use the CoreCLR (not unlike what's available for Silverlight), there's a few obscure limitations, but otherwise it's mostly there.

That said, I know Mono for iPhone has a few more limitations due to its restricted language, runtime, and app store licensing.

Comment: So i can develop Android app using C#.Net with Mono without any problem. Only slow time to run on emulator. You mean like that?
THanks you very much for your answer. :)

Comment: Generally.  You might come across an odd compatibility bug or a missing API (it's essentially running .NET 3.5ish), but it's pretty much all there.  Feel free to jump in with the free evaluation version.  If it works for you, then great.  If it doesn't, then no skin off your back except maybe some time. :)

Comment: @Onigiri BTW, even IL generation and loading/creating types at runtime works on Mono for Android (but not Mono for iPhone)

Comment: really thanks you for your effort.